# Node.js, pug. How to set a link to another pug file

Tags: javascript, node.js, pug

I'm absolutely new to pug and javascript itself. I have a little problem, can anyone please tell me what's wrong? My goal is to make several .pug files with text, so that ill be able to press on link and go to another text .pug file.I created an express app with node.js. I have a simple index.pug.

```
extends layout

block content

  h1= title
  p Welcome to #{title} 
  a(href="about.pug") this is the link text
```

So i just want to make a link from my main file index.pug to about.pug file, which is in the same folder and has absolutely same code inside. But each time i click the link it just says 404 not found (if i use website link such as www.youtube.com, link does it's task). I don't really understand...file exists, nevertheless it says 404 not found... Do i need to do some operations with routes? I haven't done any changes there.

Comment: What http server are you using?  You need to place a URL into the `href` that your http server has a defined route for and will respond to that and send the rendered `about.pug` template.

Comment: @jfriend00
It uses http://localhost:1337/ by default.
 And this is what is written in the route folder (index.js) 


`router.get('/', function (req, res) {
    res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
}); `

Answer (score 2):

So, change the href to `'/about'`:

```
(href="/about") this is the link text
```

And create a route in your Express server for it:

```
router.get('/about', (req, res) => {
    res.render('about', {title: "something"});
});
```

Comment: @BillyMilligan - If this answered your question, then you indicate that to the community here by clicking the checkmark to the left of the answer to "accept" the answer.  That will also earn you some reputation points here for following the proper procedure here.